# Access Macro Enabled Excel on Webpage using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

I need to access macro enable and external sourced excel 2003 calculator from asp.net web page. Excel accepts few values and returns some numbers post calculations.
Users are not allowed to amend/access the excel from office hence need web access to use the excel calculator features where user enter the values on webpage and pass to Excel and display results on webpage.

I tried to use sharepoint excel services due to macros's and external source on the excel file it fails excel services capability.
I would appreciate if anyone can point me in right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can try [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library). It can be integrated in ASP.NET web pages. It reads xls file macro enabled files and includes a calculator similar with the one from MS Excel.

```
// Create an instance of the class that read XLS files
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();

// Read XLS file
workbook.easy_LoadXLSFile("Excel macro enabled.xls");

// Get a sheet and compute the formulas
xlsWorksheet = (ExcelWorksheet) workbook .easy_getSheetAt(0);
String sError = xlsWorksheet.easy_computeFormulas(workbook, true);

// Check the result of the formula 
String result = xlsWorksheet.easy_getExcelTable().easy_getCell(3,0).getFormulaResultValue();
```

To display the existing values and enter later other values you can use this code:

```
DataSet ds = workbook.easy_ReadExcelWorksheet_AsDataSet(xlsWorksheet);
```

and set the DataTable as data source for a GridView for example:
http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/import-excel-to-gridview.html

EasyXLS has also some open source code (more complex) for displaying an Excel file in ASP.NET pages that can be adjusted to your needs:
http://www.easyxls.com/excel-to-gridview